# Is technical review on MDN article about "inheritance" needed?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

Below is the code,

```
function Employee() {
  this.name = "";
  this.dept = "general";
}

function WorkerBee() {
  Employee.call(this);
  this.projects = [];
}
WorkerBee.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);

var mark = new WorkerBee;
```

where [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model) says:

> The `mark` object **inherits values** for the `name` and `dept` properties from the **prototypical object** in `mark.__proto__`. It is assigned a local value for the `projects` property by the `WorkerBee` constructor.

As per the above code, constructor `WorkerBee` is explicitly calling `Employee.call(this);` but not inheriting values from `mark.__proto__`.

Presence of line `WorkerBee.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);` is irrelevant to create local values for properties `name` and `dept` in `mark` object.

Do you think the statement given in MDN is wrong in saying **inherits values**? Are the examples and imagination need to be reworked?

Comment: I think it's completely wrong, yes. There's no inheritance involved with those properties; the invocations of the "base class" constructors are just decorating the actual "child" class instance directly.

Comment: I'd edit it myself, but in my opinion the entire tutorial would need to be reworked, as it's *all* based on the fundamental misunderstanding of what those constructors are doing.

Comment: @Pointy I do not think we need to edit complete tutorial. Can you edit that paragraph?

Comment: No, if you read  the article, the entire thing is premised on that mistaken notion of how inheritance works. Note that there aren't even any prototype objects being created other than by those pointless calls to `Object.create()` - the prototype objects have no properties! All the examples need to be re-imagined and reworked.

Comment: @Pointy For beginners, Do you suggest any other tutorial that talks about this topic?

Comment: Well, there's Kyle Simpson's [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS). There are some other more accurate tutorials out there too. It's a shame that that MDN tutorial is so oddly inaccurate; I know an MDN person in Austin so I'll talk to her if I can and see what she thinks a good course of action might be.

Comment: @Pointy your recommended link just gives the github link, am looking for a tutorial that can proceed my learning. am stuck with this topic. Is this the relevant [topic](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes) for me to continue?

Comment: I'm sorry. Looks like I overlooked that sentence when [I fixed the inheritance pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model$compare?to=694747&from=613175)

Comment: @Bergi Pointy says that entire tutorial looks wrong in that page as mentioned in this comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357179/words-miswritten-in-mdn-about-prototypical-inheritance#comment52588054_32357179). Comment says: **All the examples need to be re-imagined and reworked.**.

Comment: @Bergi all the examples in that tutorial are based on the notion that those properties are *inherited* from the "Employee" base class. It goes on and on, paragraph by paragraph. None of the prototype objects have any properties on them. I think the whole deal needs to be worked over pretty thoroughly, and really I think a big example about prototype inheritance that's mostly about scalar-valued properties is a weird place to start, since it's far more common to use the prototype chain for inheriting behaviors (methods).

Comment: @Bergi maybe the problem is that some other edit broke everything. It's those lines like `Employee.call(this);` that make it all weird, I guess.

Comment: @Pointy Supplementary question. What about these  [page1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) and  [page2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) in MDN? Do you think the content looks fine?

Comment: @overexchange well "page1" looks OK, but that section "Using this for object references" has some issues.

Comment: @overexchange there's no "point of contact" really - the MDN site is a community-edited Wiki. Bergi and I (and hundreds of other people) have edited pages, and really anybody can. I'm trying to see if I can think of a not-too-big change to the examples to make that inheritance page make sense. The section on the other page I think suffers from a bad choice of example (DOM event handlers).

Comment: @Pointy: Do you know whether this is *any* point of contact for MDN, for community discussion (a forum maybe)? I've once found an IRC channel but it was pretty silent.

Comment: @Bergi no I don't; I'm not any sort of "insider", but a Mozilla employee who (I think) is mostly tasked with MDN-related stuff often shows up at local JavaScript meetups. I tweeted this issue to twitter/MozDevNet and got a response, for what that's worth.

Comment: @Pointy: Good :-) I think this feature would be essential for MDN to get higher quality docs.

Comment: @Pointy is there any technician reviewing this article?

Comment: I know that somebody with Mozilla has checked on it and agrees that it needs work, but I haven't had time lately to actually fix anything.

Comment: @Pointy is there a ticket tracking system for such serious technical reviews?

Comment: [Here is a link to the bugzilla ticket.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1201380)

Comment: **Bug 1201380**, "*Assigned To: Nobody; OK to take it and work on it*"

Comment: @Pointy As you mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357179/is-technical-review-on-mdn-article-about-inheritance-needed#comment52590344_32357179) that there are issues with topic *Using this for object references*, Would you like to raise a new ticket for the same?

Comment: [Here's the second bug.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1204224)

Answer (score 1):

Prior to ES 5 you would have written `WorkerBee.prototype = new Employee`, because there was no `Object.create`. The statement would have been somewhat correct then.

If you read on then you will actually see a diagram that shows that old code, which also omits `Employee.call(this);`.

So the answer is you are right and they forgot to update parts of the article.

Comment: It is more important to correct it. Because JS beginners take MDN as Bible, as ECMASpec is too long to read. As of now, am stuck with this topic. Can you provide an alternate tutorial that can proceed my learning?

Comment: Prior to ES5 you would have polyfilled `Object.create`.

Comment: @Bergi A polyfill requires the existence of an API to be polyfilled ;) Of course, there have been other solutions as well, but `new Base` was common practice in the old days. Obviously.

Comment: Sure :-) I think I've seen Crockford calling it `Object.beget` prior to the standardisation. Yeah, `new Base` was and unfortunately still is a common, bad practice.

Comment: @overexchange You can take a look at the books of [Axel Rauschmayer / 2ality](http://www.2ality.com/). The online versions are free. The ES 5 book is also an extensive introduction to JavaScript, whereas the ES 6 book covers the newest features of the language. The links are at the top of the page.

Comment: @Bergi: Before standardization, Crockford called it `Object.create()`. Before `Object.create()` he wrote another API that he called `{}.begetObject()`: http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html